# TLS (STARTTLS) Failure After 10.6 Upgrade to Open Directory Master

Tags: ldap, mac-osx, tls

Environment: Mac OS X 10.6.3 install/import of a MacOS X 10.5.8 Open Directory Master server.  After that upgrade, LDAP+TLS fails on our MacOS X 10.5, 10.6, CentOS, Debian, and FreeBSD clients (Apache2 and PAM).

Testing using ldapsearch:

```
ldapsearch -ZZ -H ldap://gnome.darkhorse.com -v -x -b "dc=darkhorse,dc=com" '(uid=donaldr)' uid
```

... fails with:

```
ldap_start_tls: Protocol error (2)
```

Testing adding "-d 9" fails with:

```
res_errno: 2, res_error: <unsupported extended operation>, res_matched: <>
```

Testing without requiring STARTTLS or with LDAPS:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://gnome.darkhorse.com -v -x -b "dc=darkhorse,dc=com" '(uid=donaldr)' uid
ldapsearch -H ldaps://gnome.darkhorse.com -v -x -b "dc=darkhorse,dc=com" '(uid=donaldr)' uid
```

... succeeds with:

```
# donaldr, users, darkhorse.com
dn: uid=donaldr,cn=users,dc=darkhorse,dc=com
uid: donaldr
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success
# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
result: 0 Success
```

(We are specifying "TLS_REQCERT never" in /etc/openldap/ldap.conf)

Testing with openssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect gnome.darkhorse.com:636 -showcerts -state
```

... succeeds:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
depth=1 /C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Milwaukie/O=Dark Horse Comics, Inc./OU=Dark Horse Network/CN=DHC MIS Department
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Milwaukie/O=Dark Horse Comics, Inc./OU=MIS/CN=gnome.darkhorse.com
  i:/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Milwaukie/O=Dark Horse Comics, Inc./OU=Dark Horse Network/CN=DHC MIS Department
1 s:/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Milwaukie/O=Dark Horse Comics, Inc./OU=Dark Horse Network/CN=DHC MIS Department
  i:/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Milwaukie/O=Dark Horse Comics, Inc./OU=Dark Horse Network/CN=DHC MIS Department
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<deleted for brevity>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Milwaukie/O=Dark Horse Comics, Inc./OU=MIS/CN=gnome.darkhorse.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Milwaukie/O=Dark Horse Comics, Inc./OU=Dark Horse Network/CN=DHC MIS Department
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2640 bytes and written 325 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
   Protocol  : TLSv1
   Cipher    : AES256-SHA
   Session-ID: D3F9536D3C64BAAB9424193F81F09D5C53B7D8E7CB5A9000C58E43285D983851
   Session-ID-ctx: 
   Master-Key: E224CC065924DDA6FABB89DBCC3E6BF89BEF6C0BD6E5D0B3C79E7DE927D6E97BF12219053BA2BB5B96EA2F6A44E934D3
   Key-Arg   : None
   Start Time: 1271202435
   Timeout   : 300 (sec)
   Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

So we believe that the slapd daemon is reading our certificate and writing it to LDAP clients.

Apple Server Admin adds ProgramArguments ("-h ldaps:///") to /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist and TLSCertificateFile, TLSCertificateKeyFile, TLSCACertificateFile, and TLSCertificatePassphraseTool to /etc/openldap/slapd_macosxserver.conf when enabling SSL in the LDAP section of the Open Directory service. While that appears enough for LDAPS, it  appears that this is not enough for TLS. Comparing our 10.6 and 10.5 slapd.conf and slapd_macosxserver.conf configuration files yields no clues. Replacing our certificate (generated with a self-signed ca) with an Apple Server Admin generated self signed certificate results in no change in ldapsearch results.

Setting -d to 256 in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist logs:

```
4/13/10 5:23:35 PM org.openldap.slapd[82162] conn=384 op=0 EXT oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037
4/13/10 5:23:35 PM org.openldap.slapd[82162] conn=384 op=0 do_extended: unsupported operation "1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037"
4/13/10 5:23:35 PM org.openldap.slapd[82162] conn=384 op=0 RESULT tag=120 err=2 text=unsupported extended operation
```

Any debugging advice much appreciated.

-- Tom Kishel

P.S.

Email from Apple confirms that they can reproduce this (LDAP+STARTLS fails but LDAPS succeeds on 10.6 but both work on 10.5) and have opened an internal bug report.